# Concatenate chars from one array to another in C

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a text file containing 26000 lines, or records.
Each record contains 128 bytes of hex data.

I need to pluck 4 records at a time out put it into another data structure and send it out on a socket

Here is a code snippet

```
std::string array[26000];
char* char_ptr = NULL;
char data[512];

    for(int index = 0; index <  26000; index +=  4)
    {
                    // copy data
                    char_ptr = &(array[index]);
                    memcpy(&data, char_ptr, sizeof(data));

                    // send data on socket
    }
```

This only gives every 4th 128byte record out of the string array.  How can I make this take 4 records, or 512 bytes of data from the string array and copy it into the char data[] variable

Thanks for your help

Comment: Make up your mind. Either this is C++ instead of C, or you cannot have `std::string`. If this **is** C++, what are you doing there with `memcpy()` and char arrays?

Comment: This is not C, but C++, as you are using `std::string`. I've adjusted the tag accordingly.

Comment: After second reading, this is all over the place. You are using `memcpy()` on `std::string` *objects*?

Comment: Yes, yes he is. @DevSolar

Comment: Ok  if I shouldn't use a string object for the array[] variable what syntax would a char variable take?  I used the string variable because it was a lot simpler to implement the file read.

Comment: Dear god... the problem is actually just the way you iterate the strings, but there is so much wrong with other stuff that this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Remember, `memcpy` will copy the *entire* object, which for `std::string`, includes any member variables and the string data.  Maybe you want to use `std::string::c_str()` instead of `&array[x]`.

Comment: @user2220844 You can have array of `std::string` objects (though you'd better use `std::vector<std::string>`), but you can't use `memcpy` the way you are doing it in your example. You are copying not the characters that `std::string` stores, but the binary representation of `std::string` object.

Comment: Your `memcpy` may fail because you are assuming that your `std::string` object is 512 bytes {sizeof(data)}.  I would check by printing `sizeof(std::string)` to confirm.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Both your comments are about as far off the mark as the OP's question... an (unoptimized) `std::string` will only ever hold a *pointer* to the actual data... and `sizeof(std::string)` does not help *anything* here.

Comment: @DevSolar:  The `sizeof(std::string) != sizeof(void *)` for a worthwhile `std::string`.  A valuable string structure may contain data members for size and a pointer or index to the last location.  I'm hopefully demonstrating to the OP that the size of a std::string is not the same as the string text.  Also, if the OP really wants to copy a `std::string` object using `memcpy`, the size parameter is not correct.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: The `std::string` object might **not** "include the string data" as you commented, that's implementation-defined. The OP is **not** assuming that his `std::string` are 512 bytes as you commented, he is assuming they are 128 bytes. And even if by some coincidence `sizeof(std::string) == 128`, his `memcopy` *may* not fail as you commented, it **will** fail to copy the intended data. `memcpy` on `std::string` is not well-defined even if the size parameter is correct.

Comment: @DevSolar:  The implementation of `std::string` is compiler dependent.  An implementation may have an array inside or it may use dynamic memory, as long as the interface and performance criteria are met.  Please verify that the OP specified `sizeof(data)` in the `memcpy` invocation and that the array declaration says `char data[512];`, which last time I checked, meant that `sizeof(data) == 512` not 128.  One of many issues with the program.  So, the `memcpy` function is copying *512* bytes from `&array[index]`.  Depending on the value of `index`, the memcpy may read beyond the end of the array

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: You *did* notice the loop only accessing every fourth index? He's assuming that `sizeof(std::string) == 128`. 4 * 128 == 512 == sizeof( data ). And when I said "implementation-defined", I meant just that. There is no such thing as "compiler dependent" in the language standard, especially not when talking about *library*-functions. And no implementation of `std::string` I could think of would make that `memcpy()` work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to avoid mixing C and C++ code. Here is how it can be done:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <string>

    std::string array[26000];
    const int add = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26000; i += add)
    {
        std::string data;
        data = std::accumulate(array + i, array + i + add, data);

        // send data on socket
    }
```

I'd even replaced the first array of 26000 elements on a std::vector, and replaced the constant 26000 on size() method call. Working with C-style arrays is error prone.

Comment: While I applaud the creative use of `std::accumulate` on a string, doing so without any explanation whatsoever will hardly enlighten the OP. He accepted your answer because it works for him, but I am pretty sure he does not understand *why* it works. (`std::accumulate` uses the `+=` operator to "sum up" a range of values with the third argument. That's why it is declared in `<numeric>`. Using `data` -- a `std::string` -- as the third argument will use the *string* `+=`, which is defined as concatenating strings. )

Comment: Does `data` not go out of scope at the `}`?

Comment: I agree that my answer lacks explanation. I think that the author didn't show interest in understanding how it works, unfortunately. On the other hand, the solution is more readable than memcpy or a cycle.

Comment: Sure it goes out of scope. The author meant sending the data inside the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a `std::string` is not the same thing as a byte array.

Second, the easiest way to build those four-record blocks would probably be an inner loop.

```
    for(int index = 0; index <  26000; index +=  4)
    {
                    // copy data
                    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                        assert(array[index+j].size() == 128);
                        memcpy((data)+(128*j), array[index+j]+data(), 128);
                    }

                    // send data on socket
    }
```

Last, as the other answers have pointed out, using C-style arrays is error-prone; it might be better to work with `std::string` or other STL types until later, like when you actually send the data on the socket.

Answer (score 0):

You have 26,000 `std::string` objects, each with its own internal data, not guaranteed to have internal buffers consecutive from one object to the next.  Your solution would be to revise your loop object to make use of each object separately as you populate the `data` array.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop counting variable is counting up by 4, but you're only grabbing one record. I think a better way would be to let the string object take care of memory allocation for you, then just grab the characters from the resulting string and send it out.

```
for(int i = 0; i <  26000; i +=  4)
{
    string four_recs = array[i] + array[i+1] + array[i+2] + array[i+3];

    // Extract characters
    char *byte_data = new char [four_recs.length()];
    for (int j = 0; j < four_recs.length()]; j++)
        byte_data[j] = four_recs[j];


    // Send it out
}
```

Comment: Actually he's not grabbing *one* record, he's *aiming* at the first and then just *reading* 512 bytes of data... ;-)

Comment: You're leaking memory. `std::unique_ptr<char[]> byte_data = new char[ four_recs.length() ];`.

Comment: It's assumed he's going to delete it later in the loop

Comment: **Never** assume, especially not that. Especially not since `std::unique_ptr<>` can make **sure** of it for literally zero cost.